# How can I show a logo when my android app first loading?

Tags: android

My android app's first loading time very long and it takes almost 10 seconds.During this time, the enduser sees a blank page.My question is how can show a logo during this time. I  find on internet this code but it doesnt help me :

```
 public class AppActivity extends Activity {
Boolean loading = false;
RelativeLayout r_loading;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        loading = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("loading");
    } else {
        loading = false;
    }
    r_loading=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.loading);
    if (loading) showLoadingScreen();

}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("loading", loading);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(!loading){
        showLoadingScreen();
        loading = true;
       Intent intent = new Intent(AppActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public void showLoadingScreen() {
    r_loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

}
```

Comment: You actually have to use this code in your `MainActivity`. not in a seperate `Activity`.

Comment: https://antonioleiva.com/branded-launch-screen/

Comment: @Sahil Aksit, you have to check the layout xml file `activity_app.xml` of `AppActivity`, that if there background is Image then need to compress it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a Splashscreen, there is a good tutorial here:

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

> "Implementing a splash screen the right way is a little different than
>   you might imagine. The splash view that you see has to be ready
>   immediately, even before you can inflate a layout file in your splash
>   activity.
>
> So you will not use a layout file. Instead, specify your splash
>   screen’s background as the activity’s theme background. To do this,
>   first create an XML drawable in res/drawable."

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a SplashActivity.